# SQL - LEFT JOIN with the most recent data given id and date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server Management Studio, and I'm trying to find a way to extract (with `LEFT JOIN`) the most recent data available from `table2` given a month and an id in `table1`. `table1` is the purchases given a date and a `Client_ID`:

[image]

You can see in `table1` that we have 3 clients, each purchased a certain product in the year and month specified in `YEAR_MONTH`. Now, I need some data from those clients, and for this I need to go to `table2`:

[image]

To extract the `DATA` columns (assume there are 100 columns like `DATA`). I'm looking for a way to extract the most recent data for a given `Client_ID` in a `YEAR_MONTH` of `table1`. In addition, this have a big constraint (here comes the hard part):

The **lag/delay**: The difference between `YEAR_MONTH` of `table1` and `table2` has to be minimum 1 month and maximum 7 months. Some examples:

- For `Client_ID=1` and `YEAR_MONTH=2020001` in `table1`, we need to extract the most recent data from 201906 and 201911 both included. Which in this case is 202011 so we will have "whatever3" data in `table 3`.
- For `Client_ID=2` and `YEAR_MONTH=202001` in `table1`, we need to extract the most recent data from 201906 and 201911 both included. Which in this case we have to options: 201912 and 201907. The most recent data is 201912, so we will have "whatever6" data in `table3`.

I have gone this so far:

```
    SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client_ID ORDER BY YEAR_MONTH DESC) AS Recency_ID, table2.*
    FROM table2) t
WHERE Recency_ID=1
```

Where `Recency_ID=1` is the most recent data for that `Client_ID`, `Recency_ID=2` is the second most recent data available for that `Client_ID`, etc. However, this solution doesn't respect the delay, and it will give the most recent data available from `table2` no matter the `YEAR_MONTH` of `table1` (or the lag/delay constrain). This is the output expected:

[image]

Comment: Just checking - for line 4 on your output - I would have thought it would match line 12 in Table2 (e.g., YEAR_MONTH_TABLE2 would have been 201904)?

Comment: In doing an answer, I worked out why - the 1 and 7 month boundaries are not inclusive e.g., it should be between 2 and 6 months earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the more tricky component is to work out the date ranges.

In the answer below, I started with each of the rows from Table1, then calculated the minimum and maximum Year_Months allowed - these provide the 'bounds' when joining to Table2.

Note that the horrible-looking statement

```
CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(month, -7, LTRIM(STR(Year_Month)) + '01'), 'yyyyMM') AS int) AS Min_YM
```

- First gets the Year_Month from Table1 (with original value as an int)
- Converts it to a date using the first of the month
- Subtracts 7 months
- Then converts it back to an int in the format used for Year_Month

The reason to convert to dates is for the 12-month cycle per year. Otherwise, if you were using straight ints and started with '202001' and you subtracted 7, you would result in '201994' rather than '201906'.

Ideally, you'd be working with dates not Year_Months, but given the current dataset, the above works pretty well (as in, the calculations are easy and then the joins to Table2 need no other conversions).

Then a similar query to Gordon's above pulls the more recent values from Table2 that within the 1 month/7 month bounds.

By the way, I worked out the answer to my question in comments - the 1 and 7 months are not inclusive - you actually want dates that occur before or after those.

```
WITH Table1_DateRanges AS
    (SELECT Client_ID, Year_Month, Product,
            CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(month, -7, LTRIM(STR(Year_Month)) + '01'), 'yyyyMM') AS int) AS Min_YM,
            CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(month, -1, LTRIM(STR(Year_Month)) + '01'), 'yyyyMM') AS int) AS Max_YM
    FROM    Table1
    )
SELECT  t1.Client_ID, t1.Year_Month, t1.Product, t2.Year_Month AS Year_Month_Table2, t2.Data
FROM    Table1_DateRanges t1 
        OUTER APPLY
             (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Year_Month, t2.Data
              FROM   Table2 t2
              WHERE  t1.Client_Id = t2.Client_Id 
                     AND t1.Min_YM < t2.Year_Month
                     AND t1.Max_YM > t2.Year_Month
              ORDER by t2.year_month desc
             ) t2
ORDER BY t1.Client_ID, t1.Year_Month DESC;
```

An alternate version (not using OUTER APPLY but using a LEFT JOIN and ROW_NUMBER() is as follows.

```
WITH Table1_DateRanges AS
    (SELECT Client_ID, Year_Month, Product,
            CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(month, -7, LTRIM(STR(Year_Month)) + '01'), 'yyyyMM') AS int) AS Min_YM,
            CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(month, -1, LTRIM(STR(Year_Month)) + '01'), 'yyyyMM') AS int) AS Max_YM
    FROM    Table1
    ),
PossibleResults AS
    (SELECT  t1.Client_ID, t1.Year_Month, t1.Product, t2.Year_Month AS Year_Month_Table2, t2.Data,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Client_ID, t1.Year_Month ORDER BY t2.Year_Month DESC) AS rn
    FROM    Table1_DateRanges t1 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2
               ON t1.Client_Id = t2.Client_Id 
               AND t1.Min_YM < t2.Year_Month
               AND t1.Max_YM > t2.Year_Month
     )
SELECT   Client_Id, Year_Month, Product, Year_Month_Table2, Data
FROM PossibleResults
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Client_ID, Year_Month DESC;
```

Both of these result in the following

```
Client_ID  Year_Month  Product      Year_Month_Table2  Data
1          202001      anyproduct1  201911             whatever3
2          202001      anyproduct2  201907             whatever7
2          201905      anyproduct3  201903             whatever8
3          202004      anyproduct4  202001             whatever12
3          201905      anyproduct5  NULL               NULL
3          201707      anyproduct6  201705             whatever16
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be4ca61bbf9ac0d3de05c683140266a3) with data setup and both approaches.

Comment: Hi! it seems to work (still checking). However I have three questions (1) Which solution should be faster?, (2) The line after OUTER APPLY, when you SELECT TOP 1, why aren't you selecting the TOP 1 from t2 (as usually a person would read it)? How does it works?, and (3) Related with (2), how does it works the combination of OUTER APPLY and TOP 1 there? Could you explain a little bit?

Comment: I'll start with the OUTER APPLY: What APPLY does is to run the sub-query once for each row in the original table (it is effectively a loop). For each row in the first part of the query, it runs the second part of the query and gets the TOP 1 row for it (e.g., the row with the maximum Year_Month within the relevant period). In contrast, the ROW_NUMBER sub-query does it as one run, and the ROW_NUMBER assigns a number 1, 2, 3 etc according to the Year_Months (and assigns this value as `rn`). Then in the main part, it only selects those where `rn` = 1.

Comment: Regarding which is faster - it depends on your data. The APPLY version runs a loop, so will do as many calculations as there are in Table1. However, the ROW_NUMBER versions sorts *all* the data in Table2 (not just the first rows) and then discards it all except for the first rows related to Table1. If there are many rows in Table1, but each only has a few rows in Table2, then the ROW_NUMBER version is likely to be faster. However, if there are only a few rows in Table1, each with many matching rows in Table2, the APPLY version could be faster. You really should just test and see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` for this.  I think you want:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.client_id = t1.client_id and
            t2.year_month <= t1.year_month
      order by t2.year_month desc
     ) t2;
```

This fetches the most recent `table2` row for each `table1` row, where the clients match.

Comment: Hi! But you are not considering the time window, just the most recent. Am I right?

Comment: @Chris . . . The `order by` is intended to take the time frame into account.